# Como somar valores de uma coluna na tabela?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte tabela abaixo:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="customFields">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="20%">ID</th>
      <th width="75%">Nome </th>
      <th width="5%">Qnd.</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr valign="top">

    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="148">
      <td class="text-center">148</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="148">
      <td>PH_05</td>
      <td>2560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="149">
      <td class="text-center">149</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="149">
      <td>PH_04</td>
      <td>2620</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="156">
      <td class="text-center">156</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="156">
      <td>PH_11</td>
      <td>2476</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="155">
      <td class="text-center">155</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="155">
      <td>PH_14</td>
      <td>2518</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="158">
      <td class="text-center">158</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="158">
      <td>PH_13</td>
      <td>2668</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="154">
      <td class="text-center">154</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="154">
      <td>PH_12</td>
      <td>2628</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Gostaria de somar todos os valores da `<td>` da coluna **Qnd** e mostrar logo abaixo. Qual melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Está usando alguma linguagem server side para renderizar esses dados?

Comment: @KayoBruno para essa situação tem que ser com front mesmo, js.

Comment: @acklay, algumas das respostas responde à sua pergunta? Se não, poderia deixar um comentário para o autor para dar a chance de ser adequada, se sim, aceitá-la.

Comment: @LucasCosta usei a resposta do Jefferson! Mas a sus funcionou também. Basicamente são todas bem parecidadas. +1

Comment: Que bom! Obrigado, é bom pra nossa comunidade ter retorno e quando existem respostas que funcionam e estão adequadas serem aceitas, provavelmente são priorizadas na indexação de busca =]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode definir uma `class` para seus tds e através de JS somar esses valores e por onde você quiser, segue um  exemplo de como fazer com jQuery.

```js
  $(function(){

    var valorCalculado = 0;

    $( ".valor-calculado" ).each(function() {
      valorCalculado += parseInt($( this ).text());
    });
     $( "#qtdtotal" ).text(valorCalculado);
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="customFields">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th width="20%">ID</th>
          <th width="75%">Nome </th>
          <th width="5%">Qnd.</th>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">

        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="148">
          <td class="text-center">148</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="148">
          <td>PH_05</td>
          <td class="valor-calculado">2560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="149">
          <td class="text-center">149</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="149">
          <td>PH_04</td>
          <td class="valor-calculado">2620</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="156">
          <td class="text-center">156</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="156">
          <td>PH_11</td>
          <td class="valor-calculado">2476</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="155">
          <td class="text-center">155</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="155">
          <td>PH_14</td>
          <td class="valor-calculado">2518</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="158">
          <td class="text-center">158</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="158">
          <td>PH_13</td>
          <td class="valor-calculado">2668</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="154">
          <td class="text-center">154</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="154">
          <td>PH_12</td>
          <td class="valor-calculado">2628</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="qtdtotal">
    </div>
```

Caso você não queria utilizar jQuery pode usar somente javascript puro, basta trocar o trecho de javascript que está acima por esse abaixo

```
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("valor-calculado");
  var valorcalculado = 0;
  [].forEach.call(els, function (el) 
  {
    valorcalculado += parseInt(el.innerHTML);
  });

  document.getElementById("qtdtotal").innerHTML = valorcalculado;
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode percorrer todas as últimas células de cada linha do corpo da tabela, exemplo:

```js
var total = 0;
//loop por total as últimas células de cada linha do corpo da tabela
$('table tbody tr td:last-child').each(function(){
  total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="customFields">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="20%">ID</th>
      <th width="75%">Nome </th>
      <th width="5%">Qnd.</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr valign="top">

    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="148">
      <td class="text-center">148</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="148">
      <td>PH_05</td>
      <td>2560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="149">
      <td class="text-center">149</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="149">
      <td>PH_04</td>
      <td>2620</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="156">
      <td class="text-center">156</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="156">
      <td>PH_11</td>
      <td>2476</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="155">
      <td class="text-center">155</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="155">
      <td>PH_14</td>
      <td>2518</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="158">
      <td class="text-center">158</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="158">
      <td>PH_13</td>
      <td>2668</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="154">
      <td class="text-center">154</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="154">
      <td>PH_12</td>
      <td>2628</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo funcional onde coloquei a classe qtd nas tds e peguei todas no each. Espero que ajude

```js
    $(function(){
      var total = 0;
      $('.qtd').each(function(){
        total += parseInt(jQuery(this).text());
      });
      
      $('.total').html(total);

    });
```

```css
    .total{
      float:right;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="customFields">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th width="20%">ID</th>
          <th width="75%">Nome </th>
          <th width="5%">Qnd.</th>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">

        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="148">
          <td class="text-center">148</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="148">
          <td>PH_05</td>
          <td class="qtd">2560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="149">
          <td class="text-center">149</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="149">
          <td>PH_04</td>
          <td class="qtd">2620</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="156">
          <td class="text-center">156</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="156">
          <td>PH_11</td>
          <td class="qtd">2476</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="155">
          <td class="text-center">155</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="155">
          <td>PH_14</td>
          <td class="qtd">2518</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="158">
          <td class="text-center">158</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="158">
          <td>PH_13</td>
          <td class="qtd">2668</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" id="154">
          <td class="text-center">154</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="154">
          <td>PH_12</td>
          <td class="qtd">2628</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="total"></div>
```

Comment: Acabei de fazer o mesmo código, kkkkkk!
Mas já que você já respondeu vou votar na sua! ;)

Comment: kkk desculpa, pensei que você tinha copiado.

Comment: Não da nada, ambos queremos ajudar

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de fazer, levando em consideração o índice de cada item da coluna:

```js
var posicao = 2
  , total = 0;
  
$('table tbody td').each(function(a,b){
   if (a == posicao) {
     total += Number(b.innerHTML)
     posicao += 3;
   }   
});

$('table tbody').append('<tr valign="top"><td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Total:</b> '+ total + '</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="customFields">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="20%">ID</th>
      <th width="75%">Nome </th>
      <th width="5%">Qnd.</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr valign="top">

    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="148">
      <td class="text-center">148</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="148">
      <td>PH_05</td>
      <td>2560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="149">
      <td class="text-center">149</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="149">
      <td>PH_04</td>
      <td>2620</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="156">
      <td class="text-center">156</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="156">
      <td>PH_11</td>
      <td>2476</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="155">
      <td class="text-center">155</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="155">
      <td>PH_14</td>
      <td>2518</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="158">
      <td class="text-center">158</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="158">
      <td>PH_13</td>
      <td>2668</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" id="154">
      <td class="text-center">154</td><input type="hidden" id="itemZone" value="154">
      <td>PH_12</td>
      <td>2628</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```