# Somar Total de Horas em Atraso

Tags: php

Estou com a dúvida de como eu poderia realizar a soma (formato hora) dos registros que foram retornados na consulta.

Estou pegando o horário de início de expediente considerando que acima de 08:01 ele está atrasado através dai calculando quantos minutos em atraso o colaborador está...

```
if ($GetEntrada >= '08:01:00') {
  $horaEntrada = '08:01:30';
  $entrada = $tMC['Hora_Entrada'];
  $total = (strtotime($entrada) - strtotime($horaEntrada));
  $hora = floor($total / 60 / 60);
  $minutos = round(($total - ($hora * 60 * 60)) / 60);
  $hora = str_pad($hora, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $minutos = str_pad($minutos, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $atraso = $hora.':'.$minutos;
} else {
  $atraso = "00:00";
}

echo "
  <tr>
    <td>$DataN[2]/$DataN[1]/$DataN[0]</td>
    <td>$atraso</td>
    <td>{$tMC['Hora_Entrada']}</td>
    <td>{$tMC['Hora_InicioIntervalo']}</td>
    <td>{$tMC['Hora_FimIntervalo']}</td>
    <td>{$tMC['Hora_Saida']}</td>
  </tr>
";
```

Gostaria de fazer o cálculo de todos os valores da `"<td>$atraso</td>"` como demonstrado no anexo abaixo e exibir em formato de hora.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do php esta utilizando?

Comment: Estou utilizando a Versão 5.6, se seja necessário posso fazer o update rapidamente...

Comment: *Caso seja necessário*

Comment: Olá Amigo Anderson, Este que você citou explica sobre a diferença entre duas datas, minha dúvida é um pouco diferente, Como eu faria para fazer a soma de todos os atrasos para poder definir o total de Horas em atraso (Mês inteiro) dos valores contidos na "<td>$atraso</td>"

Comment: Consegui a solução para o que precisava neste tópico pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215123/…, peço desculpas se acabei me expressando mal ou não conseguindo explicar bem, muito obrigado gente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso facilmente com a classe nativa `DateTime`:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2018-04-23 11:20:33');
$d2 = new DateTime('2018-04-23 08:01:00');

$atraso = $d1->diff($d2);

echo $atraso->format('%H:%i:%s'), PHP_EOL;  // 03:19:33
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WoozyLoudNature) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/YADizF) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/d7540e9656578272e60e3fd02c71a404)</sup>

Onde `$d1` seria o horário de entrada do funcionário e `$d2` o horário de início do expediente.

Comment: Perfeito, este eu utilizaria para ver quanto tempo o colaborador atrasou no dia 23/04/2018, mas como eu faria para fazer a soma de todos os atrasos para poder definir o total de Horas em atraso (Mês inteiro)?

Comment: @BenhurDaSilveiraKulzer nesse caso você terá que fazer um `explode` no valor e somar horas e minutos separadamente

Comment: mas caso a soma dos minutos passe 60, como eu adicionaria 1 hora e recomeçaria a soma?

Comment: @BenhurDaSilveiraKulzer divisão inteira e resto de divisão

Comment: Obrigado gente, Vou tentar aplicar esta solução e qualquer coisa eu aviso aqui novamente!

Comment: Consegui a solução para o que precisava neste tópico https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215123/como-somar-valores-de-uma-coluna-na-tabela, peço desculpas se acabei me expressando mal ou não conseguindo explicar bem, muito obrigado gente